# Creating virtual Audio device

Tags: audio, virtual-machine

There is a Linux (Manjaro) PC without an audiocard. Is it possible to create a virtual audio device? The usage idea is the following: virtual audio device process a sound, then there is a server connected to our sound channel and it transfer the sound to the client (smartphone).

Comment: PulseAudio can route audio to a different device. Perhaps there's an Android implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Pulseaudio installed: You can create all kinds of audio sinks (or "virtual audio devices", if you want) on top of the hardware sinks, no matter how many hardware sinks you have.

Have a look at the [Pulseaudio modules](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/) for details.

There are various options for an audio sink that streams the audio to other devices ("server connected to our sound channel" is not an exact description of that, because Pulseaudio itself acts as the network server, on top of being a sound server).

For example, look at the [RTP/SDP/SAP Transport module](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index7h2).