# How would I create a virtual audio device in Ubuntu?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

So basically what I want to accomplish is to capture all the raw, mixed audio coming from my system as a raw stream of audio data and send it over the network.

In terms of UX, the experience I would want to achieve would be that I can select this  "virtual audio output device" from my system settings in Ubuntu, just as if it were a pair of bluetooth headphones connected to my machine, or a projector with speakers plugged into the HDMI port for example.

What I actually want to do in my virtual audio device would be to have access to the raw audio data, so that I could chop it up into packets and send it over a UDP socket.

What would be the audio API's I would use to accomplish this?

I have done a bit of searching, and it looks like maybe implementing a PulseAudio sink is what I would need to implement?  In other words, is PulseAudio what's behind the scenes when I am choosing output devices in the settings GUI in Ubuntu 18.04?

Also, once I have created my "virtual output device", how do I get the system to recognize it as one of the output options?

Comment: There's plenty of answers how to do this either here or on superuser; search a bit.

Comment: Maybe its because of my lack of experience with the Linux audio stack, but none of these posts make the answers to my question here to me.  For instance this one :https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520983/creating-virtual-audio-device doesn't help me understand if PulseAudio is actually 1-to-1 with content of the systems settings GUI in ubuntu, or whether a PulseAudio sync is actually the component I need to get the raw mixed audio data stream handed over from the system

Comment: You will have to do some trying and more researching to know if an answer fits your needs. The accepted answer for the question you mentioned is pretty clear. [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples) gets you started with PulseAudio with working examples.